# migrating weblogic ejb 2.0 to jboss ejb 3.0

Tags: jboss, ejb, weblogic, xdoclet

We are using **`ejb 2.0`**, want to upgrade the code to **`ejb 3.1`**.

In my current code, lot of `.java` files are being automatically generated using `xdoclet` and `ejbdoclet`; I see reference to these `xdoclet` and `ejbdoclets` in my `build.xml`  file. When I remove these `xdoclet` and `ejbdoclet` code from `build.xml`, the application does not compile any longer (using `eclipse` / `ant` ).

How do I make changes to `xdoctlet` templates or get rid of these `xdoclet` and `ejbdoclet` references?

What are the `xdoclet` / `ejbdoclet` templates look like? I don't want it to auto generate it at compile time.

Comment: I remember this exact question from my last Oracle Enterprise Architect exam. The answer may sound strange at first, but it make perfect sense. If you have an existing running project that make use of ejb 2.0, you should stick to that rather than re engineering everything to ejb 3.0. At least, what you can do is to build some new ejb 3.0 that talks to ejb 2.0.

Comment: so if im not assuming you wrong , you are all suggesting me not to migrate old code to ejb 3.0 instead have newly developed ejbs which talks to ejb2.0 , FYI my current app running on weblogic , which needs to be run on jboss now .

Comment: Yes, refer to this document from Oracle: [EJB 3.0 migration](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/oc4j-twp-ejb3-migration-1013-133021.pdf). The first question you have to answer, is do you really need to migrate ? Because changes can be huge, including client code.

Comment: yes Leonardo we really need to migrate our current app which is running on weblogic to jboss EAP 6 . But the problem im facing is our developers used  xdoclet to generate nuts and bolts of ejb2.0 , In some websites most of the people mentioned that xdoclet cant be used for ejb3.0 .I know that annotations are the replacements for xdoclet tool . I run my app against windup tool which indeed highlights the places where  migration needs to be done .If you can guide me the migration process i will be much obliged . Thanks in Advance